SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'location_id' cannot be null
Check the below code I have converted this from web code , almost similar code is working on web now when I converted it into api to integrate it into app, I am facing issue:   "error": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'location_id' cannot be null"   Even tought I have set the Column 'location_id' to null and set it's default value to 0  And most weird thing is that it's creating an entry is same table as I am passing by default 1 to location_id and it shows in entry as well  then how can I receive this constraint error  Please help me to resolve this issue

public function beneficiaryAddApi() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type('json');
    $this->loadModel('Person');

    $this->Auth->userModel = 'Person';  
    $this->Person->useDbConfig = 'defaultHospital';

    // Check if the form data has been submitted
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        try {
            $email = $this->request->data['email'];
            $mobile = $this->request->data['mobile'];

            // Check if a user with the same email and mobile already exists
            $existingPerson = $this->Person->find('first', [
                'conditions' => [
                    'Person.email' => $email,
                    'Person.mobile' => $mobile
                ]
            ]);

            if (!empty($existingPerson)) {
                // User already exists
                $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => 'User with this email and mobile number already exists.'];
                return $this->response->body(json_encode($response));
            }

            // Generate the auto-generated patient ID
            $uid = $this->autoGeneratedPatientIDonline();
            
            // Save the form data into the Person model
            $this->Person->create();
            $this->request->data['Person']['patient_uid'] = $uid; // Assign the generated ID to the Person's patient_id field
            $this->request->data['Person']['first_name'] = $this->request->data['first_name'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['last_name'] = $this->request->data['last_name'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['age'] = $this->request->data['age'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['sex'] = $this->request->data['sex'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['dob'] = $this->request->data['dob'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['mobile'] = $this->request->data['mobile'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['password'] = $this->request->data['password'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['admission_type'] = $this->request->data['admission_type'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['from'] = $this->request->data['from'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['email'] = $this->request->data['email'];
            $this->request->data['Person']['location_id'] = NULL;

        
                // print_r('sdbjskfnsk');die;
            $issave = $this->Person->save($this->request->data);
            $personid = $this->Person->id;

            if ($issave) {
                 further work
            } else {
                // Error saving data into the Person model
                $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to save the person.'];
                CakeLog::write('error', 'Unable to save Person: ' . json_encode($this->Person->validationErrors));
                return $this->response->body(json_encode($response));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Log any exceptions that occur
            CakeLog::write('error', 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
            $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Internal Server Error', 'error' => $e->getMessage()];
            return $this->response->body(json_encode($response));
        }
    }

}



Please show the foreign key constraints for this table

no foreign relation is there
